# Excel — finding the difference in financial quarters

Tags: excel

There's a subtle difference between what I'm looking for and a question I could answer with a simple `datedif` formula.

Let's say I have starting dates in column A and ending dates in column B, and both date ranges run back through the beginning of 2017. Let's also say that when I refer to "quarters," I mean Q1 = January through March, Q2 = April through June, Q3 = July through September, and Q4 = October through December.

I'm looking for a formula that will tell me whether the ending date of a record is within the same quarter as the starting date and if not, how many quarters away it is.

Here's the difference between this question and one I could answer with a variation on `datedif`: If I have a starting date of 3/31 and an ending date of 4/1, those should have a difference of *one quarter* because the ending date is not within that January to March range. A variation on `datedif` would tell me that those dates are 0 quarters away from one another because the difference between the two is not at least 90 days.

Comment: will the dates ever go beyond 1 year difference?

Comment: @ScottCraner I can reduce the sample to ones that are 1 year difference or less if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

This should work although there may be a neater way:

```
=YEAR(B2)*4-YEAR(A2)*4+QUOTIENT(MONTH(B2)-1,3)-QUOTIENT(MONTH(A2)-1,3)
```

[image]